# How to create a list of objects and access to their attributes

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

I created an object N, which has some attributes, like this:

```
public class LogEvidence {
private String comment;
private String url;
private String time;

public LogEvidence(String comentario, String url, String tiempo) {
    super();
    this.comment = comentario;
    this.url = url;
    this.time = tiempo;
}

public String getComentario() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComentario(String comentario) {
    this.comment = comentario;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getTiempo() {
    return time;
}

public void setTiempo(String tiempo) {
    this.time = tiempo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LogEvidence [comentario=" + comment + ", url=" + url + ", tiempo=" + time + "]";
}
}
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
ArrayList<LogEvidence>log = new ArrayList<LogEvidence>();
```

I want go through the list and add all the attributes to my object, I mean something like this:

```
log.setComment("comment one");
log.setUrl("http://google.com");
log.setTime("04:20");
```

---

Maybe this is not possible and I have to do something like the following?

```
List list= new List();
 LogEvidence object1= new LogEvidence ();
  object1.setComment("comment");
  object1.setUrl("http://url.com");
  object1.setTime(20);
lista.add(object1);
```

Comment: You need to get an object from the list to call your accessor methods on it. `log.get(0).setComment("blah blah");` returns the first element (index `0`) from your list and calls `setComment`

Comment: Ideally the last code is the correct way

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. What is `log.setComment(...)` meant to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

Create an object of `LogEvidence`.

```
LogEvidence logEvidence = new LogEvidence();
logEvidence.setComentario("comment one");
logEvidence.setUrl("http://google.com");
logEvidence.setTiempo("04:20");
```

and add it into the array list.

```
log.add(logEvidence);
```

So, you can then create more objects and keep putting in the list. Since your list is named as `log`, so that is why you will add in `log`

Explaining it a little more, it should be something like this:

```
List<LogEvidence> logEvidenceList = new ArrayList<>();

LogEvidence logEvidence1 = new LogEvidence();
logEvidence1.setComentario("comment one");
logEvidence1.setUrl("http://google.com");
logEvidence1.setTiempo("04:20");
logEvidenceList.add(logEvidence1);

LogEvidence logEvidence2 = new LogEvidence();
logEvidence2.setComentario("comment one");
logEvidence2.setUrl("http://google.com");
logEvidence2.setTiempo("04:20");
logEvidenceList.add(logEvidence2);

....
....
....
```

Or through constructor call, this will become more concise and readable.

```
List<LogEvidence> logEvidenceList = new ArrayList<>();

LogEvidence logEvidence1 = new LogEvidence("comment one","http://google.com","04:20");
logEvidenceList.add(logEvidence1);

LogEvidence logEvidence2 = new LogEvidence("comment one","http://google.com","04:20");
logEvidenceList.add(logEvidence2);

....
....
....
```

Now, when you want to retrieve objects from the list, you can traverse the list and get one by one like;

```
for (LogEvidence evidence : logEvidenceList) {
    System.out.println(evidence);
}
```

For more information about [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Kon commented, you are trying to act upon an object that will be within the list, rather than the list itself.

There are a few ways to do this, but since you have a parameterized construtor, the easiest would be this:

```
ArrayList<LogEvidence> log = new ArrayList<LogEvidence>();
log.add(new LogEvidence("comment one", "http://url.com", "04:20");
```

---

## What's being done:

We create the list with `new ArrayList<LogEvidence>()` and assign it to a variable called `log`.

Then, we create a new `LogEvidence` object, already assigning it's data through it's constructor's parameters, with `new LogEvidence("comment one","http://url.com","04:20")`.

Since it will be stored in the list, *we can use it **anonymously***. We add it to the list directly, using the list's `.add(E e)` method, rather than assigning it to a variable.

---

You don't need to define or assign unnecessary variables, in this case.

And if you need to access any specific `LogEvidence` from the list, you can use the `.get(int index)` method. In this case, `log.get(0)`, to return the first element, would return the object you just inserted in the example code above.

You can also use a `FOR-EACH LOOP` to act upon all objects in the list, in iterating manner. Here is an example that prints the list:

```
for (LogEvidence evidence : log) {
    System.out.println(evidence);
}
```